# insert issue using batch wise in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
    CREATE  TABLE  #Tempcard
          (
          Clubcard BIGINT NULL,
         DateTime DATETIME NULL 
          ) 


    WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
       WITH EventsTop1000 
       AS
       (
       SELECT  top 200 Clubcard,DateTime 
       FROM  Clubcard 
       WHERE(DATEDIFF(DAY ,Clubcard.DateTime ,getdate())>120))
       DELETE EventsTop200
        OUTPUT DELETED.* 
        INTO #Tempcard;
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END
```

Here I am doing a Batch insertion. Once I insert the records to the `#Tempcard` table, I do not want to delete the data from the table `Clubcard`, but I need to fetch the next set of data from the `Clubcard` and again insert the data to `#Tempcard`.

If my records are 1020, I can see only 1000 records getting inserted, the rest 20 is not getting inserted.

Please let me know how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to round number of rows to 200:

```
insert into #Tempcard
select top (select count(*) / 200 * 200 from Clubcard)
       Clubcard,
       DateTime 
FROM  Clubcard 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, Clubcard.DateTime, getdate()) > 120
```

You might consider using an order by to keep things consistent.

If you are saying that you cannot insert all the records from Clubcard into #tempcard, I've tried it and it works correctly. #tempcard has 1020 records. I had to change CTE name though to EventsTop200.

**UPDATE:** question clarified.

If Clubcard can have nulls add real primary key to temporary table #Tempcard.
To copy table in batch using t-sql code:

```
CREATE  TABLE  #Tempcard
(
    Clubcard BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DateTime DATETIME NULL 
)

declare @StartClubCard bigint
set @StartClubCard = 0

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #Tempcard
   SELECT TOP 200 Clubcard, DateTime
     FROM Clubcard 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, Clubcard.DateTime, getdate()) > 120
      AND Clubcard > @StartClubCard
    ORDER BY Clubcard

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      BREAK;
   select @StartClubCard = max (Clubcard)
     from #Tempcard
END
```

There might be problems. #Tempcard might miss records inserted after procedure copied their place in a batch, or might have records deleted after copying.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to do and what the problem is. Do you want a loop that will insert 200 records at a time? If so, is there an ID field in Clubcard?

Comment: @happysmile Please read previous comment, I forgot to tag you.

Comment: what i am trying here is trying to  inserted the data from that Source to destination,i do not want to delete the data in my destination table i want to insert rows to my source table hope u got my Question now

Comment: as my table  data is huge arounf 50 million i need to insert records in batch wise from source  table to destination  where i insert 5000 records  every thime till i finsih it

Comment: @happysmile Ok. And Clubcard is primary key?

Comment: @happysmile I've expanded my answer.